# convert c# to vb.net

Tags: .net, c#-to-vb.net

can anyone pls help me convert this to vb.net

```
for each (DictionaryEntry<String, Int64> entry in characterCounter)
{
  textBox1.Text += String.Format("char {0} occurs {1} times", entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```

most of the free/online converter throw errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of [String], Int64) In characterCounter
                txtSummary.Text += String.Format("char {0} occurs {1} times", entry.Key, entry.Value)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try here: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Of course this site assumes that you have valid C# code which is not your case. There is not such operator `for each` in C#. Also the [DictionaryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.aspx) class is not generic. Here's the automatic translation:

```
For Each entry As DictionaryEntry In characterCounter
    textBox1.Text += [String].Format("char {0} occurs {1} times", entry.Key, entry.Value)
Next
```

Comment: @Smith, yes I have tried it and it worked. After fixing your code of course because as I said in my answer what you have shown here is not valid C# code.

Comment: Error: System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments.

Comment: @Smith, try removing the generic arguments or use a `KeyValuePair<string, long>`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: this > characterCounter< gives Error > Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry'. i declared it like this > Dim characterCounter As New Dictionary(Of [String], Int64)()

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each entry As DictionaryEntry In characterCounter
    textBox1.Text += String.Format("char {0} occurs {1} times", entry.Key, entry.Value)
Next
```

Comment: Error: System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments.

Comment: this > characterCounter< gives Error > Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry'. i declared it like this > Dim characterCounter As New Dictionary(Of [String], Int64)()

Comment: i fixed the problem   For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of [String], Int64) In characterCounter  ' the text in bold is underlined red
            txtSummary.Text += String.Format("char {0} occurs {1} times", entry.Key, entry.Value)
        Next

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each entry As DictionaryEntry In characterCounter
    textBox1.Text += String.Format("char {0} occurs {1} times", entry.Key, entry.Value)
Next
```

You can also try this online tool for converting c# to vb.net here: [C# to VB](http://www.defercode.com/tools/csharp-to-vb.aspx)